# Shell / Bash - Script to continue before the end of the line is running

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell / bash that works perfectly for making backups script, the problem is that I have large files that are giving problems running the script. The script has q compress the file in `tar.gz` format and it does it, but when it comes in 6GB + or the script continues compressing the file but it goes in the next lines and backups is failed, the server must have a `set_time_limit;` equal in php, the php file that calls the shell / bash I use `set_time_limit (0);` and works very well, the shell / bash has something too?

The script:

```
MYSQLDUMP="$(which mysqldump)"
$MYSQLDUMP -u $DBUSER -h $DBHOST -p$DBPASS $DBNAME | gzip > $TIMESTAMP.sql.gz

ssh $USER_SSH@$HOST_SSH "tar -zcf - $HOME" > $TIMESTAMP.backup.tar.gz

tar -zcf $TIMESTAMP.tar.gz $TIMESTAMP.backup.tar.gz $TIMESTAMP.sql.gz

SUCCESS=$?

rm $TIMESTAMP.sql.gz
rm $TIMESTAMP.backup.tar.gz
```

I did not post the variables because I think it is not necessary

Before he finished tar it removes the 2 files with the final lines ... if the file is less than about 6GB or 7GB it does not happen this

Comment: Post the script for help.

Comment: edited, waiting for you @NickBull !

Comment: i try `timeout 5h ssh $USER_SSH@$HOST_SSH "tar -zcf - $HOME" > $TIMESTAMP.backup.tar.gz` but not success